# getChildHtml not working

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, template

I have a `getChildHtml` in my `login.phtml` for my module:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('inchoo_socialconnect_google_login_button'); ?>
```

but it doesn't appear to be getting the child html

snippet of `customer_account_login.xml`:

```
<block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::inchoo/socialconnect/login.phtml">
    <block class="Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Google\Button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button" template="Inchoo_SocialConnect::inchoo/socialconnect/google/‌​button.phtml"/>
</block>
```

I think i've set the layout file out correctly but i could be wrong

Comment: use inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button in oyur phtml file, rest all is fine

Answer (score 1):

You have taken wrong name of block,

Keep below code in your phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you typed the wrong name.

It should be:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button'); ?>
```

Instead of :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('inchoo_socialconnect_google_login_button'); ?>
```

Comment: oh my days i'm an idiot

Comment: @Callum nah don't say that it happens to all of us ;)

Comment: even though the name is now correct, i get this error in the system log: "main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'Inchoo_SocialConnect::inchoo/socialconnect/google/‌​button.phtml' in module: 'Inchoo_SocialConnect' block's name: 'inchoo_socialconnect_google_login_button' [] []"

Comment: It's probably because i modifed the template file rather than the getChildHtml

Comment: @Callum yes that error usually means the path to the template is wrong

Comment: is the template file path case sensitive?

Comment: @Callum yes I think so

Comment: does "inchoo_socialconnect_login_google_button" block inherit the template file path from "inchoo_socialconnect_login"? so rather than the template file path being: "Inchoo_SocialConnect::inchoo/socialconnect/google/‌​button.phtml" it'll be: "Inchoo_SocialConnect::google/‌​button.phtml"?

Comment: @Callum no it does not. There's no such template inheritance in Magento. AS you specified a template in the template attribute it'll try to use this template.